# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark and i want to create a structured streaming for Spark to read and display the messages of Kafka topic. I am writing the following in sample.py file:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.4 pyspark-shell'
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").getOrCreate()


df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "testKafka").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()
df.printSchema()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

and I have put the spark-sql-kafka file in the jars folder inside /usr/local/spark. I am running this by writing:
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.4 sample.py but it is giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/structstream.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "testKafka").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()
  File "/usr/local/spark2.4.5/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 400, in load
  File "/usr/local/spark2.4.5/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark2.4.5/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/local/spark2.4.5/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 23 more
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It seems like that the `spark-sql-kafka` package you are adding is conflicting with some jar that spark uses for Logging. Possibly the kafka package is bringing a different version on the classpath, which is causing this error. A solution would be to find the culprit jar and add a compatible version to the classpath manually using `--packages`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

1. Scala `2.12` and Java 8 installed
2. Spark `2.4.4` downloaded (your error says you have Spark 2.4.5)

Then packages of `_` `2.12` `:2.4.4`  should just work

---

Alternative:

Use the following

```
scala_ver = '2.12'
spark_ver = '2.4.4'
spark_group = 'org.apache.spark'

packages = []
packages += f'{spark_group}:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_ver}:{spark_ver}'

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages {} pyspark-shell'.format(','.join(packages))
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I would use Spark 2.4.4  + hadoop2.7 or later, if available. Or even just the user-provided Hadoop option would work since you don't need Hadoop for Pyspark or Kafka

Comment: Or you could just not use  Spark and use a plain Python Kafka client. https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/